# Illegal characters in Path exception in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to debug code by providing some details related to address.
When I give address like `(83 S BROADVIEW ST)` I am not getting the exception, but when I give like `(1051  N DAY MIAR RD)` I am getting the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Illegal characters in Path

Any ideas why one address might be okay and the other not?

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second address has a tab character rather than spaces between `1051` and `N`. If you are using this address as part of a file or directory name, or any of the built in methods meant to work with file or directory names, that tab character is **not allowed.**

Comment: Hey Joel, thank you for the prompt response. It's indeed related to generating some reports based on the addresses and states. If the address is already in the database, the API will not be called, and the report won't be generated. Since the second address is not getting stored into DB, it is considering as a new address and API is getting called always. Is there any way to resolve this? I mean whatever unique address we give(with/without) spaces. It should store into DB.

Comment: You'll have to write code to identify the invalid characters and replace them with valid characters before calling the API.

Comment: Hi Joel,
I tried to replace as you said, and it worked fine (with just replace (vbTab," ") code. However, I am trying to create an array/list of few more special characters including vbTab but now it's not replacing. Please provide any suggestions on the below code.
Dim lst As New List(Of String) _
            From {"vbTab", "/", "\", "^", "@"}
        For Each Item As String In lst
            BuildAddr = BuildAddr.Replace(Item, " ")
        Next
Return BuildAddr

Thank You!

Comment: You want `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` and `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`